# D'Alembert's ratio test inconclusive except when for a sufficiently large $n: u_{n+1} / u_n\geqslant1$.

Tags: convergence-divergence

My textbook and Wikipedia similarly state:

Say

$r=\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}\,\left\lvert\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\right\rvert\quad$ and $\quad R=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\,\left\lvert\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\right\rvert\;$.

- If  $R < 1$, the series converges,
- If  $r > 1$, the series diverges,
- If  $r\leqslant1\leqslant R$, the test is inconclusive, except if for a sufficiently large $n: \left\lvert\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\right\rvert\geqslant1$, when the series diverges.

How can the second bullet be false, and the exception be true at the same time? (i.e. how is the exception not redundant?)

Comment: Second bullet is true and exception is also true: both specifies cases, when series diverge.

Comment: Then the exception would not be an exception, but a redundancy. I think it's unlikely that both my text book and Wikipedia both contain a redundancy.

Comment: It is exception for 3d bullet case.